# Python Requests Module: get() takes no keyword arguments

Tags: python, python-requests

I am rewriting this question to make it more concise and focused on the real problem:

test program code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kDEUxSpNMlyxPYqPw0ikUxG8INW4My8n/view?usp=sharing

implementation program code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14v06AZlGMTFMmFeaQ9cbpmNJwI33fNtS/view?usp=sharing

Currently, I have the same code that I am trying to run in the test program and the implementation program.

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = head)
```

Located in line 58 in the test program and 381 in the implementation program.
In the implementation program, that line throws this error:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = head)
TypeError: get() takes no keyword arguments
```

This does not happen in the test program. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, when you have bearer token with you, is client ID is really needed?

Well, here's how I do,

```
headers = { 'Authorization' : 'Bearer  ' + 'bd897dbb4e493881c8385f89f608d5e3bf28c656' }
r = requests.get(<url>, headers=headers, verify=False)

response = r.text
```

Please give a try.

Comment: If I get rid of the client ID, I get an authorization error on the test program and the implementation program returns the same get() error as before.

Comment: Can you please try sending the request via tool like Postman? If you can able to get response, then it's pretty sure you can response from Python code. I'm happy to help.

Comment: I have never used Postman, but I can try to figure it out. I'll let you know what happens

Comment: That was surprisingly easy, and it worked like the test program did. So I guess it's something wrong with the implementation program then?

Comment: Yes, you can figure where it's going wrong, let me know more, I'm happy to help.

Comment: The code that I posted above was inside of a function, and when I moved it to the outside, it worked. Very weird. Thanks for your help and your time.

Comment: Well, nothing to feel weird. Understand better. Move on.

Comment: The program I plan to implement uses a while loop to continuously retrieve the viewer count with the program I wrote above. When I place that code inside the while loop,  the same error happens. I guess it's about indentation then

Comment: @asdfnothing If you can isolate a the problem and post the simplest possible version of it, that can be very helpful. See here for some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

problem was that I had a dictionary named requests too. Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score -1):

The .get() function doesn't require you to specify which type of argument it is. Just input your url as a variable name into `requests.get()` like so:

```
import requests

url = # your url
r = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, in order for the API to return what I want, I need to authorize myself, and that's what the headers are for, so I can't just say requests.get(url)